# JTable spreadsheet loops forever when changing between formula and value

Tags: java, jtable

I am implementing a spreadsheet using JTable and the DefaultModel. My problem is when I enter a formula and I want to have the table update the value it goes into a loop between model.fireupdate and table changed event.
I tried removing the TableModelEvent and then adding it but it is not working.
the spreadsheet updates fine as I am printing the new calculated value in the console.
for ex:

I enter 2+3 in a cell

console shows the spreadsheet cell value = 5  works ok

the Jtable cell still shows 2+3  and causes an exception because I am trying to update the cell!

Thank you for the input.

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

    final int i = e.getFirstRow();
    final int j = e.getColumn();
    TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();

    final Object data = model.getValueAt(i, j);

    if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
        my_spreadSheet.editCell(i, j, (String) data); // updating spreadsheet cell here 
                                                      // and calculating it  This works ok
    }

     my_table.setValueAt(                                        // trying to update the jtable
     my_spreadSheet.getCellContent(jtbl_row, jtbl_col), i, j);   // here causes error.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well This is the answer. I could swear I tried this though!!! it is in my comments too but what I did wrong was not updating the table while the table listener was removed. Wierd I thought it would have removed the model listener too!

```
@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
     my_table.getModel().removeTableModelListener(this);

    final int i = e.getFirstRow();
    final int j = e.getColumn();
    TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();

    final Object data = model.getValueAt(i, j);


    if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
        my_spreadSheet.editCell(i, j, (String) data);
        my_table.setValueAt(
                my_spreadSheet.getCellValue(i, j), i, j);

    }

    my_table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
}
```